# How to get line and file name from Error in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, error-handling

Suppose I have:

```
var err = new Error('My error!');
```

How to get line and file name, where `Error` was created?
Like in PHP:

```
$ex = new \Exception();
$ex->getLine();
$ex->getFile();
```

Comment: `err.stack` can give you the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use stack-trace [node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stack-trace). This gives module name and line number

Answer (score 1):

To get the file name for the current file: use [`__filename`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_filename).

To get the folder for the current file: use [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)

To parse the file from an `Error` object, you need an `Error` with a `stack` property, that hopefully points to files. You would need then to parse the filename and line from the `stack` string or use a module that does so.

```
> new Error().stack
Error
    at repl:1:1
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:22:35)
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:73:12)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:21:12)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:346:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:545:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:7)
```