# Getting error line number from catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
try{
    cause error  
}
catch(err){  
    console.log(err.lineNumber) //or console.log(err.line)
}
```

The error object supports multiple things such as err.name, err.stack, and err.message but I can't find anything that works for logging the line of the error and filename. For example the stack actually shows the information I want that being "loader.js:13:22" but it's also the full stack. I'm sorry if this isn't a question I should be asking here but I've tried many "solutions" that haven't worked. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Used this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/stack-trace supports everything I could ever need, thanks all.

Comment: Take a look at this, I think that's a similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200503/how-to-get-line-and-file-name-from-error-in-node-js

Answer (score -1):

```
var stack = error.stack;
var stackLines = stack.split('\n');
var lineNumber;
for (var i = 0; i < stackLines.length; i++) {
  if (stackLines[i].includes(__filename)) {
   var lineMatch = stackLines[i].match(/:(\d+):(\d+)/);
   lineNumber = lineMatch ? lineMatch[1] : undefined;
   break;
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).