# How to get the current module's file path in a node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I want to print the correct filepath even if the function is imported in some other module inorder to handle the errors correctly. How can I do that? I am using serverless stack.

Please refer the following code,

```js
class Logger {
  filePath: string;
  
  constructor(fp: string) {
    filePath = fp;
  }
  
  printLog(info) {
    const { timestamp, message } = info;
    
    return `${timestamp} ${filePath}: ${message}`;
  }
}
```

This is used in `dbConnection.ts` as,

```js
const logger = new Logger(__filename);

export const connectToDB = () => {
  try {
    //DB connection code.
  } catch(error) {
    logger.print({ timestamp: new Date().toISOString(), message: error.message });
  }
};
```

Now, I want to connect to db from some other module lets say, `test.ts` then I will use it as follows,

```js
export const test = () => {
  //some code here...
  
  connectToDB();
  
}
```

When there occurs an error while connecting to DB, then It prints something like this,

`2022-05-27T05:24:47.548Z src/test.ts: Error in connecting DB url is unreachable please check your internet connection.`

In order to have proper debuggability, I want to print the filename from where the exception is actually thrown. That is `src/dbConnection.ts` and not `src/test.ts`.

Comment: You can't get a filename from where an exception came from unless it's already in the exception Error object you have, so if you want to make sure it's there, then make sure the code that throws sets it for you.  You can get the filename of the currently executing module, but not some other module.

Comment: How about a `re-throw`?

Comment: @NalinRanjan can you explain in detail?

Comment: In `src/test.ts` catch for errors in call to `connectToDB()` and then throw an error again... that way you will have both errors at your disposal... or do whatever you want to with this `rethrown` error which also carries with itself an `inner error`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get line and file name from Error in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200503/how-to-get-line-and-file-name-from-error-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

If in module:

```js
console.log(import.meta.url)
```

Works in browser, not sure if available with Node imports.

Answer (score -2):

Try using

```
__filename
```

`__filename`: This will return the path of the file executing

`__dirname`: This will return the path of the directory in which the file executing is located.

Check if it does what you need like

```
console.log(__filename);
```

Comment: In the question I am already using the same thing and not getting the correct filename and you answered the same thing again which does not solve the issue.

Answer (score -3):

Try to change `filePath` to `this.filePath` in your Logger  Class